# How to login and get api_token with native Laravel auth system

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I got an API (no web) app with Laravel 5.3. I'm trying to use native token functionality. I can register a user and get token back but I don't know how to login and authenticate a user with credentials (email and password).

I don't find any doc about that. Is it possible without using third party package ?

If I use login function from LoginController

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()
```

Comment: You should not be validating a user, using email and password over your API. API should strictly use API tokens.

Comment: @MinaAbadir Right, but in order to get a token a user must give me credentials no ?

Comment: Yes through normal web app, not the API part.

Comment: Hum! Sorry I still don't understand how can I login a user to my API from the mobile app for exemple ? Or how can I create a new user from a mobile app ? Should I use JWT-auth package ?

Comment: OK, in that case, you need to make a route in your API that accepts the email/password, and authenticate them. Make sure, that this route is not protected by API middleware.

Comment: Ok it's what I did but I still have this error!

Comment: Add your Controller and routes code please.

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)
```